# Is there a shop selling vegan sneakers in France?

Tags: veganism, clothing, fabric

Are there any vegan sneakers that you can actually try physically before buying in France? Most of the (European) brands that I've found so far only sell online.

I know that Vans has some vegan sneakers but I was looking for something different.

Comment: LOL. Seeing the question title, I was thinking "VANS authentic, dude, someone in most every city sells them..."

Answer (score 2):

I was in this situation a couple of weeks ago and I came across this brand, [**Veja**](http://www.veja-store.com/fr/190-vegan)

Not all their shoes are vegan but they have a nice vegan selection and it is possible to find them in some physical stores.

P.S. I am not associated in any way with this brand.